# Python String to Decimal Conversion - Weird results

Tags: python-2.7, decimal

I'm using the Decimal module in python and seeing some rather weird behaviour when converting strings.

```
print "orig = %s dec = %.19f" % (rate,Decimal(rate))
```

Results in:

```
orig = 0.0151 dec = 0.0151000000000000006
orig = 0.00995 dec = 0.0099500000000000005
orig = 0.011075 dec = 0.0110749999999999998
orig = 0.0123 dec = 0.0123000000000000002
orig = 0.01 dec = 0.0100000000000000002
orig = 0.047025 dec = 0.0470249999999999974
```

Perhaps even more concerning rounding of Decimals seems to also produce bizarre results

```
print "orig = %.19f rep = %.19f" % (originalCashflow,replacementCashflow)
originalCashflow = originalCashflow.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
replacementCashflow = replacementCashflow.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
print "orig = %.19f rep = %.19f" % (originalCashflow,replacementCashflow)
```

Results in:

```
orig = -10028392.3750000000000000000 rep = -10028392.3750000000000000000
orig = -10028392.3800000008195638657 rep = -10028392.3699999991804361343
```

This doesn't seem right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do know that float number is NOT accurate from the beginning, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: and by not accurate you mean?

Comment: There are many articles about floating number accuracy, including this one https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html from python documents. Due to how float number are stored in memory, the real stored value of a float number is only an approximation to the original decimal fraction, and thus not accurate at all.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't converting strings.  You are converting floats.

```
orig = 0.0151
orig_str = "0.0151"

decimal.Decimal(orig)
```

Output:

```
Decimal('0.01510000000000000057454041524351850966922938823699951171875')
```

String conversion is exact.

```
decimal.Decimal(orig_str)
```

Output:

```
Decimal('0.0151')
```

[Floats are not exact.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)